# Unable to compile the sample code from the beginning of section 4 of the algorithm2e package manual

Tags: algorithm2e

In trying to run a piece of code listed in the manual of the `algorithm2e` package, I got a compilation error. Could you please help me debug it?

The manual is available on [the package's CTAN page](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e). The manual version I use is the current one, namely release 5.2 of July 18 2017. The code listing I am trying to run is the one in the beginning of section 4 on p. 8. Here it is with some additions described after the listing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[boxed,commentsnumbered,longend]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand{\forcond}{$i=0$ \KwTo $n$}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\SetKwFunction{FRecurs}{FnRecursive}%
\Fn(\tcc*[h]{algorithm as a recursive function}){\FRecurs{some args}}{
\KwData{Some input data\\these inputs can be displayed on several lines and one
input can be wider than line’s width.}
\KwResult{Same for output data}
\tcc{this is a comment to tell you that we will now really start code}
\If(\tcc*[h]{a simple if but with a comment on the same line}){this is true}{
we do that, else nothing\;
\tcc{we will include other if so you can see this is possible}
\eIf{we agree that}{
we do that\;
}{
else we will do a more complicated if using else if\;
\uIf{this first condition is true}{
we do that\;
}
\uElseIf{this other condition is true}{
this is done\tcc*[r]{else if}
}
\Else{
in other case, we do this\tcc*[r]{else}
}
}
}
\tcc{now loops}
\For{\forcond}{
a for loop\;
}
\While{$i<n$}{
a while loop including a repeat--until loop\;
\Repeat{this end condition}{
do this things\;
}
}
They are many other possibilities and customization possible that you have to
discover by reading the documentation.
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I used the package options `boxed,commentsnumbered,longend` as described in the bottom of p. 8. I defined the command `\forcond` as described on p. 8. I added to the algorithm the line `\SetKwFunction{FRecurs}{FnRecursive}` as described on p. 8.

According to the manual, this code is supposed to typeset as follows.

[image: Expected output]

However, when I try to compile the code with LuaLaTeX the compilation fails with the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \Fn
     (\tcc*[h]{algorithm as a recursive function}){\FRecurs{some args}}{
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.9 
  
End of file on the terminal!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document you reference (you should have it and its tex source installed locally,not just on ctan) says

> The algorithm 7 shows how algorithm looks like with a python-style syntax. To achieve this
> display, we need to make following changes before the algorithm:

```
\SetStartEndCondition{ }{}{}%
\SetKwProg{Fn}{def}{\string:}{}
\SetKwFunction{Range}{range}%%
\SetKw{KwTo}{in}\SetKwFor{For}{for}{\string:}{}%
\SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{:}{elif}{else:}{}%
\SetKwFor{While}{while}{:}{fintq}%
\renewcommand{\forcond}{$i$ \KwTo\Range{$n$}}
\AlgoDontDisplayBlockMarkers\SetAlgoNoEnd\SetAlgoNoLine%
```

the line

`\SetKwProg{Fn}{def}{\string:}{}`

would define `\Fn` that you show as undefined.

Comment: Thank you, David. But the quote you cited from the manual pertains to Algorithm 7, whereas I'm interested in Algorithm 4, on p. 8. With regards to Algorithm 4 the manual has this to say: "The algorithm 4 shows how algorithm is displayed in pseudo-code with default behaviour and options boxed, commentsnumbered and longend set." and the listing that follows is the one that I embedded in my original post. Therefore, I'm not sure your post answers my question.

Comment: I added the line you suggested and recompiled. The compilation succeeded, but the output doesn't equal the one in the listing of Algorithm 4.

Comment: @EvanAad shrug, it's using `\Fd` in several examples and shows a definition of it, for on of them, as perhaps a minor doc improvement you could suggest to the package author but not anything to confusing, (I just searched the doc for `\Fd`) apart from that you don't need to look at the pdf at all. You have the tex source for the document you show so you an look at the source to see how that algorithm was typeset

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, you're right. I can simply read the manual's source code. It hadn't occurred to me. Thanks!